# FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. When a column is in a parent that does

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place a text inside my widget tree, the problem is that whenever the text is long, it overflows, i am trying to create something that gives it a new line whenever it overflows, i have tried multiple solutions with all leading me to same error,

FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.

any way this can be fixed?

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: xx,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return xx;
        } else { 
          return Padding( 
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row( 
                  children: [ 
                    Container(
                     // some widgets,
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column( 
                            children: [ 
                              Flexible(
                                child: Text(
                                  text ,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible, 
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ), 
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: Actually it works without Flexible

Comment: i agree you have used Fexible + Expanded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yeasin Sheikh, I just removed Flexible, my bad.